# HTML object element overwrites following elements

Tags: html

I'm embedding a .pdf file in a page like this:

```
<div id="main">
<object type="application/pdf" data="/blah.pdf" width="675" height="830" />
<p>other HTML elements<p>
</div>
```

where:

```
#main
{
    width: 675px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

The .pdf renders with the size I specify, but elements following the object element (such as the p element) don't get rendered, or are overwritten.

It's like this both in the latest IE and Firefox.  Know what's wrong?

Comment: Any way you can put this in a jsFiddle ?

Answer (score 3):

`object` element's are not self-closing. So the HTML parser will turn it into:

```
<div id="main">
    <object type="application/pdf" data="/blah.pdf" width="675" height="830">
        <p>other HTML elements<p>
    </object>
</div>
```

The contents of the `<object>` element are shown if the replaced content *isn't* shown, and therefor your paragraph (and anything else before the closing `</div>` tag) will be hidden from view.

Comment: I encountered the same situation: HTML content following an `<object>` element not rendering!  Adding a closing tag, `</object>`, solved the issue.